# Prove or disprove: the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is independent of the choice of basis on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, hilbert-spaces

I have found this question here:

[Question on why Hilbert-Schmidt operator definition is independent of the choice of basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270144/question-on-why-hilbert-schmidt-operator-definition-is-independent-of-the-choice).

But I do not understand the answer. Also I feel like my question is different as I am asking about  Hilbert-Schmidt **norm** and not **operator**, am I correct?

1-If so can anyone give me a hint to the  answer of my question?

2-If I am incorrect can anyone explain to me the answer in the above link in a clear way please?

**EDIT:**

In the solution that is given in the link above:

I do not know why he considered the given linear transformation unitary or orthogonal, could anyone explain this for me please?

**EDIT2:**

**The statement in general is false (it is true only for orthonormal basis) ..... can anyone give me an example for showing that it is false please?**

Comment: Hilbert Schmidt norm is defined for Hilbert Schmidt operators so this question is already answered in the earlier post. Which part of the proof you had difficulty with?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  the general consequence of the steps of the proof is not clear for me ..... what did he do to prove the required?

Comment: I even do not understand where is the solution in the link mentioned @hopefully

Comment: My professor said that this statement is wrong and its correct only if we have an orthonormal basis @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the proof, which is quite simple (and is true even in countably many dimensions, too, with minimal modifications, over either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).

If $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ is an *orthonormal* basis, the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $A$ is defined as

$$\| A \| ^2 = \sum _{i=1} ^n \| A e_i \| ^2 = \sum _{i=1} ^n \langle A e_i, A e_i \rangle = \sum _{i=1} ^n \langle A^t A e_i, e_i \rangle = \operatorname{Tr} (A^tA) \ ,$$

where $A^t$ denotes the transpose of $A$.

Now, if $\{ f_1, \dots, f_n \}$ is another *orthonormal* basis, let $M$ be the transition matrix between them, i.e. $f_i = \sum _j M_{ij} e_j$. Since it is a transition matrix between *orthonormal* bases, $M$ will be *orthogonal*, i.e. $M^t M = I_n$ or, equivalently, $\sum _{j=1} ^n (M^t)_{ij} M_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$, with $\delta_{ik}$ being Kronecker's symbol.

Then

$$\sum _{j=1} ^n \| A f_j \| ^2 = \sum _{j=1} ^n \langle A f_j, A f_j \rangle = \sum _{j=1} ^n \langle A^t A f_j, f_j \rangle = \sum _{j=1} ^n \langle A^t A \sum _{i=1} ^n M_{ji} e_i, \sum _{k=1} ^n M_{jk} e_k \rangle = \\
= \sum _{i = 1} ^n \sum _{k = 1} ^n \langle A^t A e_i, e_k \rangle \sum _{j = 1} ^n M_{ji} M_{jk} = \sum _{i = 1} ^n \sum _{k = 1} ^n \langle A^t A e_i, e_k \rangle \sum _{j = 1} ^n (M^t)_{ij} M_{jk} = \sum _{i = 1} ^n \sum _{k = 1} ^n \langle A^t A e_i, e_k \rangle \delta_{ik} = \\
\sum _{i = 1} ^n \langle A^t A e_i, e_i \rangle = \| A \| ^2 \ ,$$

which shows that, indeed, the definition of $\| A \|$ does not depend on the *orthonormal* basis used.

If one does not use orthonormal bases, though, the above ceases to hold. Probably the simplest illustration of this is to take $A : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $Ax = x$. Take $e_1 = 1$ and $f_1 = 2$. The Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $A$ in the basis $\{ e_1 \}$ is $\sum _{i=1} ^1 \| A e_i \| ^2 = | A e_1 | ^2 = |e_1|^2 = 1^2 = 1$, while the norm in the basis $\{ f_1 \}$ is $|A f_1|^2 = |f_1|^2 = 4$. This happens because the basis $\{ f_1 \}$ is not orthonomal, since $\| f_1 \| ^2 = f_1 \cdot f_1 = 2 \cdot 2 = 4 \ne 1$.

Comment: why in the forth line the last inequality the trace appears? what rule are you using?

Comment: @hopefully: Yes, there were some missing squares, I have added them. Regarding you question about the trace, for an arbitrary matrix $B = (B_{ij}) _{1 \le i,j \le n}$ it is true that $\operatorname {Tr} (B) = \sum _{i = 1} ^n B_{ii} = \sum _{i = 1} ^n \langle e_i, B e_i \rangle = \sum _{i = 1} ^n \langle B^t e_i, e_i \rangle$. Now use that $(A^t A) = (A^t A) ^t$.

Comment: Does not the example should be from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ ? because the question asks this.

Comment: @hopefully: And I'm giving you a counterexample when $n=1$.

Comment: How is $B_{ii} = <e_{i} , Be_{i}>$?

Comment: @hopefully: Since $B e_i = \sum _j B_{ij} e_j$, we have $\langle e_i, B e_i \rangle = \langle e_i, \sum _j B_{ij} e_j \rangle = \sum _j B_{ij} \langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \sum _j B_{ij} \delta_{ij} = B_{ii}$. We have $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ because the basis is orthonormal.

Comment: Could you please look at this question when you have time ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177056/show-that-the-characters-of-the-representations-phi-n-of-su2-constitute

Comment: is your first equality a way for describing matrix elements

Comment: @hopefully: This is how you define the matrix elements of a linear operator in a basis.