# Injective mapping theorem proof discrepancy.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I do not understand from where the 2 comes in the proof of letter(a) of the statement of the theorem:

[image]

And this is proposition 12.2.4

[image]

I think the author has used the mean value inequality, but I do not know how, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: My answer should clear some of this up for you.  The lemma I refer to is a bit involved but I can give you a reference.

Comment: Thank you I know this lemma @RRL

Comment: @RRL  I am sorry .... but it is just mentioned before the theorem ..... it seems like my concentration is weak today.

Comment: Yes -- it should use the mean value inequality $\|f(u) - f(v)\| \leqslant \|Df(c)(u-v)\|$ for some $c$ on the segment joining $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Proposition 12.2.4, since $Df(c)$ is injective the exists a constant $\gamma'$ such that  $\|Df(c)(u)\| \geqslant \gamma'\|u\|$.  This is easily proved by using the fact that a linear operator is continuous and attains a maximum and minimum on the (compact) unit sphere.

We can define $\gamma = \frac{1}{2}\gamma'$ so that $\|Df(c)(u)\| \geqslant \gamma'\|u\| \geqslant 2\gamma\|u\|$.

There is a **lemma** that states if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then given $\gamma > 0$, for all points $u$ and $v$ sufficiently close to $c$, i.e. in the ball $B$ centered at $c$, we have

$$\|f(u) - f(v) - Df(c)(u-v)\| \leqslant \gamma \|u-v\|$$

The proof does, in fact, use the mean value theorem.

By the reverse triangle inequality,

$$\|Df(c)(u-v)\| - \|f(u) - f(v)\|\leqslant\|f(u) - f(v) - Df(c)(u-v)\| \leqslant \gamma \|u-v\| $$

Hence,

$$\|f(u) - f(v)\| \geqslant \|Df(c)(u-v)\| - \gamma \|u-v\| \geqslant  2\gamma\|u-v\| - \gamma \|u-v\| = \gamma \|u-v\|$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170545/prove-or-disprove-the-hilbert-schmidt-norm-is-independent-of-the-choice-of-basi    could you please look at this question for me if you have time?

Comment: @hopefully: Ok I'll take a look shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I appreciate it